# Variable passing context

Tags: php, string

First my code:

```
<?php
  ...
  $name = 'Schlagi123';
  echo "Hi {$name}";
  ...
?>
```

Now the context of the String is the current context of the script, function, etc. 
Is it possible to set the context of the string to another object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot. And I think it's much better that you cannot have such behavior.
Anyway I suggest you to change the syntax to:

```
$name = 'Schlagi123';
echo "Hi {$name}";
```

That is much more clear.

Altho you can use anonymous function to mimic your request:

```
$string = function($var) {
    return "Hello {$var}";
};

echo $string('hello');
```